# jQuery $.when() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have three functions. One is an AJAX call, one is a callback function given to this AJAX function, and the last one is a completely independent function that waits for the AJAX functions to finish. The third function has to remain completely independent from the AJAX function, it can not be passed as a parameter to the AJAX function. My code:

```
doAjaxStuff: function(callbackFunction){
     $.ajax(
          // do AJAX call
          // With the AJAX data, create HTML div elements 
          callbackFunction();
     )
}

callMeMaybe: function(data){
     //do stuff with the return data from the AJAX call
}

patientFunction: function(){
    $.when(this.doAjaxStuff).done(function(){
         alert("doAjaxStuff() has finished!");
         // do stuff to the created HTML div elements.
    });
}
```

But I never get the alert message to show up. The AJAX call and callback function are performed succesfully, but the $.when() function is never triggered. What is going wrong in this code?

Comment: Q: Do you mean to call `callMeMaybe` with the data from the ajax call?

Comment: I recommend $.ajax().always() for 3rd function.

`$.ajax()
          .done()
           .fail()
           .always()`

always will trigger when the ajax finish everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use `when` you need to return the ajax deferred/promise from your `doAjaxStuff` method:

```
doAjaxStuff: function(callbackFunction){
     return $.ajax(
          // do AJAX call
          callbackFunction();
     )
}
```

As you mention, the callback needs to be supplied with the current syntax, but with promises you no longer need callbacks.

```
doAjaxStuff: function(){
     return $.ajax(
          // do AJAX call
     );
}
```

Call with:

```
patientFunction: function(){
    var self = this;   // Need to retain a reference to this
    $.when(this.doAjaxStuff()).done(function(data){
         alert("doAjaxStuff() has finished!");
         // do stuff to the created HTML div elements.
         self.callMeMaybe(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Also another error I made: if you call the function in the when method with parentheses, the AJAX function expects parameters. If you use $.when(this.doAjaxStuff) instead of doAjaxStuff() it works. Otherwise it expects you supply it with a callback function.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not completely working yet. I'll add some more detail to my code.

Comment: @Bas: Please do. That green tick flashing on and off is giving me a headache :)

Comment: Sorry. But it does grab your attention. :P 

The problem is that in the AJAX call, div elements are created. These elements are edited in the independent function. However, even though the AJAX method returns and is done, the div elements still appear to not be on the page when the independent function executes. What to do?

Comment: You are now referencing code that is not shown... can you put the whole thing in a JSFiddle? I can mock the Ajax calls in that.

Comment: That final edit did it for some reason. Time to study my code to see what happened! Thanks for your patience and help, the correct answer is now definitive.